# Do I need to include Java EE maven dependencies in POM.xml if I develop my application against Glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am developing a Java EE application and I intend to run it on an Java EE Application Server (I have chosen Glassfish).

I know Glassfish is a reference implementation (RI) of the Java EE platform and it implements/contains individual reference implementations of the Java EE specifications. Correct me if i'm wrong but this leads me to understand that the binaries of Glassfish will contain all the relevant RIs jars inside it.

I am using Maven as my build/project management system and I will build/package my application up in a WAR file (because my application is a Java EE web application). Then I will deploy this WAR onto my Application Server - Glassfish and then it runs.

My question is, do I need to specify the Java EE dependencies in my Maven pom.xml file?

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and at the moment I need to include those dependencies otherwise Eclipse will not recognise the Java EE sources - it will complain with compile time errors.

But if I do include in my pom.xml then does that not mean I'm duplicating the external dependencies (Java EE RI jars) in my application (in the WAR file) whereas an Application Server like Glassfish already provides it? because Maven downloads those jars and put into your code base - right?

for.eg (just using JMS as an example):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

do I need above? I know I definitely do if I were developing against Tomcat because it is a Servlet container and doesn't have the other full Java EE specifications.

- this is the part where I'm a bit confused about and I hope someone will shed a light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need to mark them with scope `provided` telling Maven that it should use them when compiling, but during runtime the implementation is provided by the application server, so they shouldn't be packaged into the WAR.

Comment: And those are the Java EE API jars, not those of the Reference Implementation jars.

Comment: may I ask what is the difference between Java EE API jars and RI jars? and when will I use/need each of those types of Jars?

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper The API can be used to compile against, but there's no actual implementation. During runtime there is an actual implementation (whether it's the RI or some other implementation), so the code can actually run.

Comment: I see. I understand now. So for compilation we provide the dependencies with the 'provided' scope and don't package it into the WAR. Once deployed onto the server it will use the RI jars provided by the Application Server i'm using.

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper Yes, this means that you can develop without caring which implementation is actually going to be used (at least in theory).

Answer (score 3):

GlassFish already has the Java EE jars, but you will need it for compilation purpose so you have to add a dependency for those jars but provide the scope as "provided" so these jars will not be bundled in your war or ear file. please see below example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```